# Is it possible to pass a table valued parameter to a stored procedure and return a table result?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'd like to create a stored procedure that takes a table argument and returns a separate (schema) table result set.

First, is this possible?

Second, am I on the right track or completely off?

My Procedure Definition

```
USE MyDatabaseName

-- drop the procedure so we can recreate it
IF (OBJECT_ID('doit')) is NOT NULL DROP PROCEDURE doit
GO

-- drop and recreate the type in case we want to change how its defined
IF TYPE_ID(N'MyTableType') IS NOT NULL DROP TYPE MyTableType
CREATE TYPE MyTableType AS TABLE(keyvalue bigint NOT NULL, datevalue date NOT NULL)
GO

-- create procedure
CREATE PROCEDURE doit ( @indata MyTableType READONLY )
AS

-- Ultimately, real work will be done here that accumulates
-- a result set and returns it.  For now, we just return
-- a sub-set of what we were passed to see if this will
-- work...Which, it doesn't seem to.

RETURN SELECT top 100 keyvalue, datevalue FROM @indata

GO
```

My calling code:

```
-- Call the doit procedure

declare @myargtable MyTableType

-- Gather my 'doit' argument
INSERT INTO @myargtable select top 1000 my_bigint_field, my_date_field from my_source_table;

-- This output is what I expect 'doit' to produce.
select top 100 * from @myargtable

-- Get a result table ready for the output of 'doit'
declare @results MyTableType

-- Store the results.
insert into @results EXEC doit @myargtable

-- I expect this to give me 100 records like above.
-- But, it gives me none.
select * from @results
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the RETURN from the SP definition so the line is just

```
SELECT top 100 keyvalue, datevalue FROM @indata
```

Answer (score 1):

A stored procedure can only return an int as a return value.

Perhaps you meant to either simply `SELECT` your results to return them:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE doit ( @indata MyTableType READONLY )
AS
   SELECT top 100 keyvalue, datevalue FROM @indata

   RETURN 0
```

Or use a table-valued function instead:

```
CREATE FUNCTION doit ( @indata MyTableType READONLY )
RETURNS @t TABLE (
    keyvalue bigint,
    datevalue date )
AS

    insert into @t
    select top 100 keyvalue, datevalue
    from @indata

    return
```

Or even an inline function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION doit ( @indata MyTableType READONLY )
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN (
    select top 100 keyvalue, datevalue
    from @indata
)
```

Comment: I didn't down vote you so not sure about that. A stored procedure is what I want - I've determined that's what I need to build.  Seems like my confusion was just about the 'RETURN' keyword.  Removing that is the solution to my problem. as RyanB has above.  Thanks!